# Programmatically add constraint to view relative to a sibling

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I am using Auto Layout. I have a view with a subview (sb1). I am programmatically adding another subview (sb2) to this view. I am adding constraints to this new subview.

What I want accomplish:

add sb2 below sb1 an add a constraint to the top of sb2 to pin it to sb1.

What I've tried:

```
[self.containerView insertSubview:sb1
                     belowSubview:sb2];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sb1 
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                     toItem:sb2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];

[self.otherLeftView addConstraint:constraint];
```

What is happening is my newly added subview is being pinned to the top of the container view, NOT to the sb1 (which is what I want to happen). Visual of what is happening:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can add a constraint between SB1 and SB2? Thanks!

Comment: You're constraining both their tops to be equal, and that's exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @JoshCaswell how can I add a vertical spacing constraint then?

Comment: null's answer has the general idea: constrain the top of the second to the _bottom_ of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sb1 
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                     toItem:sb2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];
```